# Vite alias @ import from shared project

Tags: typescript, vite

I have two pure Typescript projects, each in their directory with their own node_modules and vite.build.mjs.

The project structure looks as follows

```
/project-1/
  - src/
    - service-1/
    - service-2/
  - vite.build.mjs      // Uses `vite.build` in "lib" mode on each service index.ts

/project-2/
  - src/
    - client/
    - interface/
  - vite.config.mjs
```

The build for `/project-1` contains the following alias

```
{ find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
{ find: '@p2', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('../project-2/src/', import.meta.url)) },
```

The config for `/project-2` contains the following alias

```
{ find: '@', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)) },
```

---

The issue is in `project-1` I have the following code

```
import { client } from '@p2/client'
```

and in the `project-2` client file I have

```
import interface from '@/interface'
```

This then fails because it tries to resolve the `@` in `project-2` with the resolve of `project-1`. The error is

```
Can not resolve {dir}/src/interface from {dir-of-project-1}
```

Is there any way around this?